# jquery sequence of fadeIn animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-animate, fadein

I'm using `jQuery`, `fancybox` and `vgrid` library(http://blog.xlune.com/2009/09/vgrid/demo007.html)

I want to achieve some sequential fadeIn animation. This is the part of my code doing this:

```
  array2=[]
  for(item in data_array)
    {

      _item= $(data_array[item]).hide()
      vg.prepend(_item);
      array2.push(_item)
    }

   $('a[rel=fancybox]').fancybox(
    {'transitionIn':'elastic', 'transitionOut':'elastic', 'titlePosition':'inside', }   
    );    
  ctr=0;
  seqAnim=function()
  {
    alert('seqAnim '+ctr+', '+array2.length+" , "+array2[ctr]);
    if(ctr!=array2.length)
    {
      array2[ctr].show();
      alert('fading in');
      array2[ctr++].fadeIn(300, seqAnim);
      alert('done fading in');
    }
    else
    {
//         $('a[rel=fancybox]').fancybox(
//  {'transitionIn':'elastic', 'transitionOut':'elastic', 'titlePosition':'inside', }   
//  );    
    alert('all done');
    }
  }

  vg.vgrefresh(null, null, null, seqAnim)
```

this might not be the best way of doing so but it is working. At least in FF and Chrome. but in ***ie9***, it is not working. I've been trying to debug it with `alert` calls but I can't find the bug. the alert calls in `seqAnim` function pop up only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try doing something like this for sequential animations:

```
var data_array = ["#item1", "#item2", "#item3"],
    //instead of a loop, join the selectors together
    //and wrap them at the same time.
    $items = $(data_array.join(',')).hide(),
    animLen = 1000;

$('a[rel=fancybox]').fancybox(
    {'transitionIn':'elastic', 'transitionOut':'elastic', 'titlePosition':'inside', }   
);

$items.each(function(i, item) {
    var $item = $(item);

    $item.delay(i * animLen).queue('fadeInQueue', function(next) {
        $(this).fadeIn(animLen);
        next();
    }).dequeue('fadeInQueue');
});

vg.vgrefresh(null, null, null, seqAnim);
```

**Edit**

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HNuMD/5/) of it working. I've tested it in IE9, and FF8 and it working in both places.